# correct method of tiling using tile adhesive according to american standards

Tags: tile

i m planning for new house construction and marble tiles will be everywhere,
marble setbacks, marble cladding, marble interior floor. this Saudi engineer
have explained and demonstrated the correct method of tiling according to
American standard, but i want to make sure first and confirm this is the best
method. i cannot train labor to use this method out of a YouTube video.
my only question is that: can you please give me the official papers of the
American standard that support this method and his saying.
he is saying to put tile adhesive on both the tile back and the substrate (back butter).
the bigger the tile size the bigger the square notched trowel size.
trowel size is half on tile back and double on substrate.
i made a summery of this method as an image below.
you can also check the video but it is in Arabic language.
[tiles correct method video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjuhJWOKLqU)
[image: tiles correct method summery]

Comment: Proper methods of application of mastic or thinset mortar, ( and which to use) is best determined by the tile manufacturer

Comment: Tlle Council of North America: https://tcnatile.com they publish standards. Most cost money.

Comment: Of course the American method is best. Nobody has a deeper tiling history than the US. And you don't want BS from the Brits, do you? Seriously, they prefix their standards with a "BS." USA! USA! USA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ceramic tile installation there's an ANSI specification, A108. For natural stone tile the Marble Institute of America publishes the DSDM, *Dimension Stone Design Manual*. These are the documents that you would cite in a contract to get US workmanship standards. The *TCNA Handbook* is a collection of tile installation details rated for dry areas, wet areas, indoors, and outdoors. It's a pretty good alternative resource to both of the above standards because it also contains workmanship standards for both ceramic tile and natural stone tile (these workmanship standards are taken from both of the above documents). A108 and the DSDM are the actual standards, however, and they go into far more workmanship detail than the *TCNA Handbook*.

- Flat back troweling ("back buttering") is considered necessary for natural stone tile like your marble, so that's correct.
- Notched back troweling ("buttering") performed after flat back troweling is considered optional, but will increase the likelihood of achieving sufficient coverage, so it's a good practice. Technically notched back troweling is only required for tiles 36"×36" (1m×1m) and larger, though, so unless the tile is, say, 12"×24" (300mm×600mm) or larger, this step is a waste of time. It's important that the notch directions are aligned on the tile and substrate. I think this is intuitive for most installers, so I wouldn't worry too much about misaligned notches.
- Running thinset notches the shortest distance possible maximizes coverage by providing the shortest escape distance possible for air under the tile, so that's a good practice.
- Your 90% coverage is considered inadequate for most natural stone tile. For marble tile 5/8" (16mm) and thinner, the DSDM specification is 95% coverage with no voids within 2" (50mm) of corners and no voids larger than 2 in² (1250 mm²) anywhere. For marble tile 3/4" (19mm) and thicker the DSDM specification is 80% coverage with the other void constraints unchanged.
- You should periodically remove a just-installed tile to verify that you're meeting the coverage specification. There's no official method for choosing trowel notch sizes. Pulling up a tile to check coverage is how you verify that the notch sizes are adequate.
- Somehow collapsing the ridges is a requirement for achieving adequate coverage. Moving the tiles perpendicular to the thinset ridges is the best method.
- Sneaking up on workers to pull up an occasional tile is a good idea so that you get an accurate impression of the coverage achieved. The trowel's incline angle when applying thinset can reduce the total thinset applied. Variation in ridge-collapsing movement impacts coverage. A formal test may not accurately represent the tile installation's typical coverage. It's rude under US culture, though. Probably rude over there, too. A third party inspector or a diligent boss are valuable partly in how they spare you from insulting workers by checking up on them.

And your use of the term "tile adhesive" is confusing. There are organic adhesives for installing tile and there are cement-based thinsets. The organic adhesive type is typically appropriate for dry locations with 8" tile and smaller (I think there exist organic adhesives for large format tile, but I've never actually seen it). The cement-based thinsets provide better quality. Based on your video and square notch trowel, I assumed that you were talking about cement-based thinset. The organic adhesive type is typically applied with v-notch trowels.